# PHP class or function or convert Northern Ireland eastings and northings to lat and long

Tags: php, geocoding

I have some data of Northern Ireland postcodes with eastings and northings for each postcode. Does anyone know of a class or function I can use in PHP to convert these to latitude and longitude values? Or does anyone know if this data exists anywhere with the latitude and longitude values already?

I found a good class to convert eastings and northings to latitude and longitude but it only works for Britain. Northern Ireland has a separate map grid.

Comment: OK sorry ... I will remove my comment ...

Comment: Please show the data you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, lot of zip/postal code + geolocation class exists. 
See on [phpclasses site](http://phpclasses.org)

But directly the projects here:

- [city lookuper](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2959-PHP-Lookup-for-cities-and-zip-codes-using-AJAX.html)
- [main distance](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/522-PHP-Locate-near-zip-codes-and-distance-between-them.html)
- [geographical distances & lat/long.](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4938-PHP-Retrieve-geographical-location-for-given-zip-codes.html)